# How do I deploy a JSP file in the Jetty webserver?

Tags: jsp, jetty, file-structure

I have created a simple JSP file that I want to deploy in Jetty 7.2. Jetty is running and I can see the default web page at `http://localhost:8080/`. I started Jetty with the `java -jar start.jar` command.

I saved my simple JSP file `jsp_test.jsp` at `<my_jetty_directory>/webapps/jsp_test.jsp` and then I tried to access that file on `http://localhost:8080/jsp_test.jsp` and `http://localhost:8080/webapps/jsp_test.jsp` but none of them works.

Is there something more I have to do? Where in the Jetty file structure should I place my JSP file?

If you know a helpful tutorial I would be thankful. I haven't found any good ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place it in a folder inside webapps:

`webapps/myapp` -> `http://localhost:8080/myapp/test.jsp`

Comment: Thanks, that is a step closer. Now I get `HTTP ERROR: 503; Problem accessing /test/jsp_test.jsp. Reason: Service Unavailable` ...does this mean that JSP isn't started by default by Jetty? I added some information to my question.

Comment: @Jonas - check the log files. If the context has failed to start, there should be something there.

Comment: I installed a new Jetty, and did like you described. Now is it working perfectly. Thanks. Now I'm going to learn how to do Serlvets.

Comment: I got a similar problem with Servlets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122629/how-do-i-deploy-a-servlet-in-jetty